# Chavitti uzhichil course in Kerala

Tags: budget, india, kerala, study

I'm looking for a course in [Chavitti uzhichil](http://www.arshayoga.com/tr_ch.htm) (massage using feet) in Kerala that is as cheap as possible (approximately 200 euros). No need for accommodation or food as part of the course. I need it for April 2012.

Comment: "Chavitti uzhichil" is a treatment which is massaging the body using foot. Ayurvedic medicinal oils are used for this treatment. It is used to cure any inner injuries of body muscles or bones. "Chavitti uzhichil course" which you meant is the course of treatment to be taken ie; number of days/number of massages and definitely not something to learn.

Answer (score 3):

It's vague as to whether you mean 'a course of being treated' or a course to learn.  Assuming treated, you could consider:

[Kerala Ayurveda](http://www.arshayoga.com/tr_ch.htm) - a training school, they have a course of 7 or 14 days. It can be extended as well.  It seems they do education AND treatment, so that should satisfy either of the possible requirements that you're after.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late reply. But for anyone else who's looking for ayurvedic rejuvenation, here is the list of Kerala government authorized Ayurvedic centers. Stay safe and welcome to God's own country..

https://www.keralatourism.org/ayurveda-centres

Comment: Welcome to Travel! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: If a detail of specific place is used, then it would be considered as a promotion, right?